# Does Poisson Distribution means the system is chaotic?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, non-linear-systems, chaos-theory, complex-systems, integrable-systems

The [Berry-Tabor Conjecture](https://www.google.com/search?as_epq=berry+tabor+conjecture) says that for classically integrable systems, the corresponding quantum systems obey the Poisson distribution for their energy-level spacing. But generally, the integrable systems do not show chaos. Does Poisson distribution mean the quantum system may show chaos for large energies?

Comment: I am missing some assumption here, why would you associate Poisson distribution with chaos ?